# jQuery toggle opens all hidden divs

Tags: jquery

In the code below, I'm trying to `show/hide` the `toolOptions` span, when a  clicks on the `<i class="icon-user user-icon"></i>`. Right now, they'll show, but not just the one I click on, it'll show all. Is there a possibility of getting only the span that's under than icon to show?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-js">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Stack Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/site/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".user-icon").click(function(){
            $(".toolOptions").toggle();
        });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .toolOptions{
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>


    <body>

    <div class="user">
    <span>User Name</span>
    <span class="tools"><i class="icon-user user-icon"></i>
    <span class="toolOptions">
        <li>Option A</li>
        <li>Option B</li>
        <li>Option C</li>
        <li>Option D</li>
    </span>
    </span>
    </div>

    <div class="user">
    <span>User Name</span>
    <span class="tools"><i class="icon-user user-icon"></i>
    <span class="toolOptions">
        <li>Option A</li>
        <li>Option B</li>
        <li>Option C</li>
        <li>Option D</li>
    </span>
    </span>
    </div>

    <div class="user">
    <span>User Name</span>
    <span class="tools"><i class="icon-user user-icon"></i>
    <span class="toolOptions">
        <li>Option A</li>
        <li>Option B</li>
        <li>Option C</li>
        <li>Option D</li>
    </span>
    </span>
    </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What `$(".toolOptions")` means is "gather all of the elements with a class of `toolOptions`". You need to be more specific with your selector.

Comment: Also, FYI you don't need both `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` and `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. Just put `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in before the `<title>`.

Comment: @OllyHodgson Still testing things. They'll go later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select element by class name and in your HTML multiple elements have `toolOptions` class, so if you use class selector than it's give than it's select all elements with the given class.

If you want to apply effect only a specific element, you need to set specific selector rule to select element.

As your requirement, you want to select next span of clicked icon. than you can use `.next()` :

```
 $(".user-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toolOptions").toggle();
 });
```

OR

```
 $(".user-icon").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find(".toolOptions").toggle();
 });
```

OR

```
 $(".user-icon").click(function(){
       $(this).closest(".toolOptions").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to target only the next sibling element of the clicked `user-icon` element

```
    $(".user-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toolOptions").toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `next()`

```
    $(".user-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toolOptions").toggle();
    });
```

as a side note, your markup is invalid. Use a validator to fix errors.

Comment: Uh... Invalid where? I ran through my code a couple of time and cant find something invalid.

Comment: list-items should be properly wrapped in <ul>, <ol>. Not as descendents of <span>

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".toolOptions").toggle();
```

Refers all the elements with the class name.  So try to refer the closest element using **`.closest()`**.

```
 $(".user-icon").click(function(){
            $(this).closest(".toolOptions").toggle();
        });
```